# Trigger RXJS Stream only on certain condition

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I have two tabs on my UI.

First tab (default), there is one input textbox and when user submits it, a http call is sent to server

Second tab - Same input textbox + list of checkboxes out of which at least one has to be selected. Then on submit http call is sent.

Both of these cases work fine by themselves.

Now, the problem is - I want my stream to trigger only when form is submitted and not on tab switch. However, I do want the value of tab clicked.
However, currently after the form is submitted once, its being triggered on every tab switch as well ( probably because then it has both selected tab & account available).

Below is the code snippet.

I am not sure what i am missing. Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

```
detailsByAccount$: Observable<MyType> = this.selectedTab$.pipe(
switchMap((tab) => {
   //account$ = account submitted through form
  return this.account$.pipe(
    switchMap((account) => {
      alert(`${account} -------- ${tab}`);
      // Server Http call to get the response
      if (tab === 'X') {
        return this.myService.getDetails(account)  
      }
      return this.myService.getOtherDetails(account);
    })
  );
}),
);
```

Comment: need to see account$ stream code

Comment: Its just a behaviorSubject and On form submit I am doing next with account number. Nothing else going on with it

Comment: so on form submit you call next() on account$?

Comment: Yes, accountSubject.next(account)

Comment: because account$ it will always emit when you subscribe(), even that is from the history. that's why you got such issue. I'll suggest you switchMap to individual form.submit (2 of them) stream instead

Comment: So diff form for both cases?

Comment: Yes, or use subject for account$ instead of behaviorSubject your code would probably work.

Comment: I will check. Thanks for your help

Comment: @FanCheung - Just changing BehaviorSubject to Subject did the trick. Thanks

Comment: Glad it helps  you

Answer (score 1):

i would do it like this:

```
  detailsByAccount$: Observable<MyType> = this.account$.pipe(
    withLatestFrom(this.selectedTab$),
    switchMap(([account, tab]) => {
      alert(`${account} -------- ${tab}`);
      // Server Http call to get the response
      if (tab === 'X') {
        return this.myService.getDetails(account)  
      }
      return this.myService.getOtherDetails(account);
    })
  );
```

the `withLatestFrom` operator will not trigger the stream but when `account$` is triggered, it will grab the latest value from `selectedTab$` and pass it along. It will not trigger though if `selectedTab$` has not emitted at least once.

Comment: This looks good. Cleaner as well. I just tried it and it works. So till yesterday I didn't have single way to do this and now I have two. Such is life :) . Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

So for this scenario, turns out I had to use BehaviorSubject and it made things little tricky. Below is the answer that I ended up using. Any improvements/optimizations are always appreciated.

Premise of Question  -
Two tabs –
Input form.
Input form with a list of checkboxes.

There is a different validator for different tabs. Whenever the form validation passes, form submit is enabled.

Two important things to consider are – Tab has to be selected and the stream should be triggered only after form is submitted.

My first approach was mentioned in the question. However, the issue was http call was being made on every tab switch.

Now,  to fix it what I did was – I refactored it so it’s triggered always on account submitted rather than tab selected and then I used take(1) in the inner stream, so it completes itself every time. After I did this this issue got resolved.

```
detailsByAccount$: Observable<MyType> = this.account$.pipe(
  switchMap((account) => {
    return this.selectedTab$.pipe(
      switchMap((tab) => {
        alert(`${account} -------- ${tab}`);
        // Server Http call to get the response
        if (tab === 'X') {
          return this.myService.getDetails(account);
        }
        return this.myService.getOtherDetails(account);
      }),
  take(1)
 );
})
);
```

Hope this helps someone. If anyone has any better suggestions, please let me know.

Happy Learning

Vatsal